# 2 users sharing PC, both using uTorrent

Tags: utorrent

2 users sharing a pc (admin & guest) both using uTorrent & downloading different torrents.

After a Microsoft update & shutdown/reboot, upon booting again it returns only one functional uTorrent & the both users' uTorrent torrent lists are the same (one list is erased).

The users are upset each time because they have to figure out what was downloading and get them up and running again. Waste of time each week.

How can we reboot the PC with 2 different sets of torrents still running afterwards?

Comment: Do they have separate Windows accounts?

Answer (score 0):

uTorrent is probably not able to support multiple concurrent users, as it probably wasn't written with that in mind.

It sounds like it's sharing a file (and/or memory range) and when the two different users' uTorrent client persists the torrent list to disk (at shutdown), both instances of it are saving to the same file, and the last one to write to it is the list that's saved to disk.

People running Terminal Servers are well aware of this relatively common problem with desktop applications. :)

Either find a Torrent client that's aware of multiple concurrent users/instances, or perhaps just have each person use a different torrent client.

Alternatively, perhaps consider using a virtualization solution to separate the users out into different virtual machines on the same PC.

Comment: Thanks for such a quick reply Techie007. I will try, as you suggested, just having each of us use a different torrent client. I would prefer to run one program though. However, does anyone know of a torrent client that's aware of multiple concurrent users/instances as suggested? Thanks to anyone with help!